# How do I cancel action of a form after an alert?

Tags: javascript, python

When the user submits the form, `writeToStorage` is fired and it checks if the user is in localStorage and if it is, an alert is run. After this alert I don't want the action to execute. I tried `return false;` but obviously that does not stop the python script from running. How do I stop the action of the form in case the alert is triggered?

```
function writeToStorage() { 
  var chooser = localStorage.getItem("chooser");
  if (chooser) {
    alert("you are already a user);
    //return false; }
  else {
    //the rest of the program } };

# if alert is run the action of the form should not run
<form name="choice_form" id="choice_form" action="/g/choicehandler" method="post" onsubmit="writeToStorage()">
  <textarea name="choice" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea><br />
  <input type="hidden" name="chooser" id="form_chooser" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit your choice">
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add your `return false` back in and also change:

```
onsubmit="writeToStorage()"
```

To:

```
onsubmit="return writeToStorage();"
```

Comment: Great thanks! I noticed that I was missing the ";" in `onsubmit="writeToStorage()"`. Is that always necessary in similar situations and can you explain with more details why this works? Thanks again.

Comment: You don't need the semicolon there, it's optional. It's my preference to include semicolons at the end of a block in Javascript, so I like to include one there too.

Comment: @Zeynel This works because `writeToStorage();` returns false, but `writeToStorage();` isn't your event handler, and you want your event handler to return false. You need to return the return value of writeToStorage from your event handler. So that if writeToStorage returns false your event handler will also return false.